# if not and if not find string python

Tags: python

Tearing my hair out (what litte I have) with python (2.7 on raspbian).

Both these work

```
if reply.find(alivereply) != -1:
        print 'Node alive'
        
if reply.find(tagstring) != -1:
        print 'Tag string received'
```

But when I try to say if either (alivereply) or (tagstring) are not present then the string is invalid

i.e.

```
if not ((reply.find(alivereply) != -1) and (reply.find(tagstring) != -1)):

if ((reply.find(alivereply) == -1) and (reply.find(tagstring) == -1)):

if reply.find(alivereply) == -1:
    if reply.find(tagstring) == -1:
        print 'invalid string'
```

They all report all strings (even valid ones) as invalid

If have tried various combinations of if, if not, if any and, if and if, if not and if not

Any thoughts appreciated.
Life is so much simpler with other languages.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `or` instead of `and` in your case?

Comment: Tried or, same result

Comment: maybe use brackets like this: ```if (not ((reply.find(alivereply) != -1)) and ...```

Comment: The formatting on your bottom code snippet doesn't make much sense. What's wrong with `if reply.find(alivereply) == -1 or reply.find(tagstring) == -1: print("one of the two failed")`?

Comment: Sven, you may be a life saver, does this look right ?                     if (not ((reply.find(alivereply) != -1)) and ((reply.find(tagstring) != -1))):

Comment: A more pythonic way should be like this:
`if alivereply not in reply and tagstring not in reply:`

Comment: Instead of `.find() == -1` you could easily use `'a' in 'abc'` or similar, `not in` works as well.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am trying to be too clever finding two character strings or not!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Spoke too soon,  if (not ((reply.find(alivereply) != -1)) and ((reply.find(tagstring) != -1))):  doesn't work